# Why Glassmapper's Editable field doesnt invoke Sitecore RenderField pipeline

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, glass-mapper

In Sitecore MVC, we are using the following construct to display the field data in our views:

> @Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc.GlassView.Editable(s => s.Field)

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to invoke the RenderFieldPipeline, unless I use

> @Html.@Sitecore.Field("field", item)

Is there a way to invoke the RenderFieldPipeline with the glassmapper's Editable construct? Just curious why would GM behave this way.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For performance considerations, the renderField pipeline is not invoked by design (except in edit mode). See [this discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/issues/98).

As mentioned in the GitHub issue, if you only need this for single-line text fields, you can activate a setting in your annotation:

```
[SitecoreField(Setting = SitecoreFieldSettings.ForceRenderField)]
public virtual string MyField { get; set; }
```

You could also:

- Use your own extension method [as described here](https://cardinalcore.co.uk/2016/05/09/life-through-a-lens-extending-and-modifying-glass-rendering-output/);
- [Create a custom mapper](http://www.glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial19) which handles your transformation needs.
- Create an extension method which then calls the pipeline by overriding Glass, [as detailed in this blog post](http://www.robertgray.net.au/posts/utilising-the-render-field-pipeline-when-using-glass-for-sitecore).

The exact approach will depend on your level of comfort and the exact reason you need to use the pipeline.